# Character Encoding not working for Japanese ,Chinese and Korean

Tags: java, unicode, encoding, character-encoding, streamwriter

I have Unicode characters for all the European countries and for a few Asian countries like Japan, China, Korean. All the Unicodes are working fine for European countries except for Japan, China, Korean.

Example for Japan:

```
dear_name=\u30c7\u30a3\u30fc\u30e9\u30fc
```

Example for China:

```
dear_name=\u4eb2\u7231\u7684
```

Example for Korean:

```
dear_name=\uce5c\uc560\ud558\ub294
```

Example for Sweden (this one is working fine):

```
dear_name=Till
```

Default character encoding is UTF-8.

```
Template template = VelocityFactory.getTemplate("test.vm", "UTF-8");
   String messageText = VelocityFactory.merge(context, template, charset);
```

While debuging the merge method I found out that  the merged result is getting grabled here itself for chinese,Japanese,korean.

```
public static String merge(VelocityContext context, Template template, String charset) throws Exception {

        String newResult = null;

        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        OutputStreamWriter streamWriter;
        if(charset != null && charset.length() > 0) {
            streamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, charset);
        } else {
            streamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream);
        }

        template.merge(context, streamWriter);
        streamWriter.close(); 

        mergedResult = outputStream.toString();                 
        outputStream.close();

        return newResult;        
    }
}
```

Below is the mail template and only for header it is displaying in correct format for Japanese, Chinese, and Korean, but not for the body:

```html
<html>
    <head>      
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="$contentType">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content">
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin-left: 0px;">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="textBody" style="margin-bottom: 120px;">
                            <tr>
                                <td valign="bottom" class="mainHeader" nowrap>
                                    $velocityUtils.getMessage("test")
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2">
                                    <img src="$imageBar" class="clipped">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <div id="info" class="textBody">$velocityUtils.getMessage("test1")<br><br></div>    
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any information how to fix this? How do i encode correctly??

Answer (score 0):

try adding this to the top of your JSP

```
<%@ page language="java" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

Comment: It is not a jsp page.It is vm file.

Comment: Same requirement though,  Have a look at http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web/64372-setting-content-encoding-in-velocity

Answer (score 0):

you need to specify the character sets for japanese, korean and chinese

```
For japanese try: charset=iso-2022-jp
For korean try: charset=iso-2022-kr
For chinese try: charset=big5
```

Comment: Thanks ..I am getting this issue only while sending emails to user and there also the header part is displayed correctly for all the Asian languages but the body get grabled

Comment: email clients use the content type defined in the header and not in the meta-tag....

so your safest bet is to convert the body content i.e. all special characters to their HTML entities and you won't have to worry about the header Content-Type again...

use an online converter tool to convert your content>>>

[example converter tool](https://www.emailonacid.com/character-converter)